# Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ a convex function. Show that $A:=\{x\in I : f(x)<0\}$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of the following claim I found in a past exam:

**Claim:** Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ a convex function. Then $A:=\{x\in I : f(x)<0\}$ is open.

**Proof:** Let $x\in A$ and $y\in I$. Since f is convex we know that

$f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)\leq\theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y)$

From which it follows that:

1. if $f(y)\leq 0$, then $f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)<0$ for all $\theta\in(0,1]$.
2. if $f(y)>0$, then $\theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y)<0$ for $1-\theta<\frac{1}{1+\frac{f(y)}{|f(x)|}}$

**Question 1**

3. To show the first bullet point I would say the following: $\theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y)=\theta(f(x)-f(y))+f(y)\leq 1\cdot (f(x)-f(y))+f(y)=f(x)<0$
4. Why $1-\theta<\frac{1}{1+\frac{f(y)}{|f(x)|}}$ ? I got the following $\theta(f(x)-f(y))+f(y)<0\iff \theta<-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)-f(y)}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}}$. Because $\theta\in[0,1]$ I guess we need to take $|f(y)|$. Then $\theta<\frac{1}{1-\frac{f(x)}{|f(y)|}}$
5. Does $1-\theta<\frac{1}{1+\frac{f(y)}{|f(x)|}}$ follow from $\theta<-\frac{|f(y)|}{f(x)-|f(y)|}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{f(x)}{|f(y)|}}$?

**Question 2** Now the construction of the neighbourhood of $x$ is shown, which I don't get either.

By the above in both cases there is a $\theta_{0}<1$ such that $f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)<0$ for all $\theta\in[\theta_{0},1]$.

If $y<x$ let $\epsilon:=(1-\theta_{0})(x-y)$ apperently this implies that $[x-\epsilon,x]\subseteq A$
If $y>x$  let $\tilde{\epsilon}:=(1-\theta_{0})(y-x)$ this implies that $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]\subseteq A$

**Question 3** Why is $\epsilon:=(1-\theta_{0})(x-y)$? I don't see why this definition works and how to come up with it.

The next step is I thin okay.

Take $r:=\min\{\epsilon,\tilde{\epsilon}\}$, then $(x-r,x+r)\subset A$.

I really have given it some thought but unfortunately I don't get my head around this proof. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you know that convex function is automatically continuous (and a lot more, for example, left-hand and right-hand derivatives always exist and are increasing functions of the independent variable $x$)?

Comment: I am afraid all of that is not allowed to be used.

Comment: Just get any textbook and read the proof that "convex function is continuous".

Comment: Are you saying that the above proof is basically the proof that f is continuous or would you use continuity to show that A is open?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, $A$ is open. Clearly $A = f^{-1} ( (-\infty, 0) )$, the inverse image of the open set $(-\infty, 0)$ under $f$.

Comment: Okay apperently i am missing something, but what about $x^2-1$? I would tray to express A as a union of open sets, which I get from the fact that f is continuous. Would that work?